# Angular js getting error must define $get factory method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am getting error in firebug.

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module autoQuote due to:
>   [$injector:pget] Provider 'function prepareDtoFactory()' must define $get factory method.

My code fo angular js controller is as below.

```
angular
.module("autoQuote")
.controller(dtoController)
.factory(prepareDtoFactory);

function dtoController(prepareDtoFactory){
     prepareDtoFactory.rc1Step1DTO(); //call function from your service, and do something with it
}

dtoController.$inject = ['prepareDtoFactory'];

function prepareDtoFactory(){

    var prepareAutoQuoteDTO = {
        postAutoQuoteObj         : $.getAutoQuoteObject(),  
        initializeDriverObj: function(){
            var driverLocObj           = new Driver();
            driverLocObj.PersonInfo    = new PersonInfo();
            driverLocObj.DriverLicense = new DriverLicense();
            driverLocObj.Incident      = new Incident();
            return driverLocObj;
       },
       initializeAppInfo: function(){
           var appInfoLocObj           = new ApplicationInfo();
           appInfoLocObj.Discount      = new Discount();
           return appInfoLocObj;
       },
       /*
       * Initialize Vehicle object for autoQuoteDTO.js
       */
       initializeVehicleObj: function(){
           var vehicleLocObj = new Vehicle();
           return vehicleLocObj;
       },
       /*
       * store session info
       */
       rc1Step1DTO: function(){

            var emailId = $('#save_quote_email').val();
            if (typeof emailId  !== "undefined" && emailId && emailId != '' && emailId != 'Email Address'){
                var email           = new Email();
                email.EmailTypeCd   = 'PRIMARY';
                email.EmailAddress  = emailId;
                this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo =     this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo || new Contact();
                this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails = [];
                this.postAutoQuoteObj.ApplicationInfo.GeneralPartyInfo.ContactInfo.Emails.push(email);
            }
        }
    };
    return prepareAutoQuoteDTO;
}
```

created plunker with all files

Please help me to fix this error.
http://plnkr.co/edit/VJKrDRMJY3Q73bsCgVwX?p=preview

Comment: I don't get error opening demo in either chrome or firefox

Comment: I am getting error, when running this in local system.

Comment: But demo doesn't represent error. Doesn't even have the improper controller as noted in answer. Hard to debug something that is working. See [mcve]. Somewhere you have an incorrect injection something like : `app.controller('A', function($scope,prepareDtoFactory()){` ... note the function in the injection argument

Comment: prepared code in plunker and want to make it working. When I will submit from  step1 factory method should call. but getting even when included controller file i index.

Comment: No idea what that means or if demo reproduces problem now or not and if it does how to see it

Comment: please download plunker and error can be  reproduced in localhost. let me know ow to ineject factory and call factory method on form submit.

Comment: Have no interest in downloading plunker and setting up on localhost. Can do anything in plunker you can on localhost

Answer (score 1):

The controller and factory functions with angular take two parameters: the name of the service or controller, and the function. Changing those to .controller('dtoController', dtoController) should help.